# Electromagnetic Field for one dimensional Electromagnetic Standing Wave

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, magnetic-fields

I have started reading a book about quantum mechanics (by Eisberg and Resnick) in first chapter it states that

"The electric field for one-dimensional electromagnetic standing waves can be described mathematically by the function
E($x,t$) = $E_0$ sin (2$\pi$$x$/$\lambda$) sin (2$\piνt$)"

Where did this equation came from?

Comment: This is well explained in the [Wikipedia article on electromagnetic waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave_equation#The_origin_of_the_electromagnetic_wave_equation).

Comment: Do Eisberg and Resnick explain how they can make a one dimensional electric wave? No such thing can exist. Maxwell's equations require three dimensions to define the relationship between electric and magnetic components properly. Another door stop?

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Please see physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation/ for typesetting formulas. Also, consider providing the chapter/page and a bit more of context - that might make it easier to give you an answer.

Comment: do electromagnetic wave create a electromagnetic field? if so what is the equations of field?(let it be in three dimension)

Comment: Have you tried looking for the answer in a general physics textbook, or a book on electromagnetism? This site is not a substitute for making an effort to do your own research.